# Leaflet.js / Browser returns 500 internal server errors for missing tiles' files

Tags: javascript, leaflet

File:
    http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet-src.js

Brief:
Browser return 500 internal server errors for missing tiles' files. This issue is adding run-time to load the map with all layers.

Issue:
I've used the software MapTiler to create a layer as an overlay of a another layer (Base Layer) of a custom floor plan. The Overlay has a lot of transparency and MapTiler generates tiles' files only for the areas where there are images. As a result the browser returns lots of 500 internal server error as it looks for all tiles including the ones that MapTiler wouldn't generate. I've attached one example bellow.

Expectation:
Leaflet would try to load only tiles that actually exist.

E.g.:
    GET http://local.leaflettest/map/layers/labels/4/9/6.png 500 (Internal Server Error) leaflet-src.js:2983
    L.TileLayer.L.Class.extend._loadTile leaflet-src.js:2983
    L.TileLayer.L.Class.extend._addTile leaflet-src.js:2856
    L.TileLayer.L.Class.extend._addTilesFromCenterOut leaflet-src.js:2763
    L.TileLayer.L.Class.extend._update leaflet-src.js:2721
    L.TileLayer.L.Class.extend.onAdd leaflet-src.js:2508
    L.Map.L.Class.extend._layerAdd leaflet-src.js:2255
    L.Map.L.Class.extend.addLayer leaflet-src.js:1713
    L.LayerGroup.L.Class.extend.eachLayer leaflet-src.js:4381
    L.LayerGroup.L.Class.extend.onAdd leaflet-src.js:4366
    L.Map.L.Class.extend._layerAdd leaflet-src.js:2255
    L.Map.L.Class.extend.addLayer leaflet-src.js:1713
    L.Control.Layers.L.Control.extend._onInputClick leaflet-src.js:8595
handler

Comment: Are you sure there is a setting in MapTiler? I once used the same stuff you're using and for me it would just generate black tiles where there's no image avilable

Comment: I'm using MapTile START. It only have 3 Advanced Options and I've try it all. :(

Comment: Oh no wait, now I remember, I tried MapTiler and it didn't work for me neither, after that I kept searching and ended up using a photoshop plugin called zoomify: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/10/17/photoshop-zoomify-in-html-powered-by-leaflet/

Comment: This question has already been [asked and answered on the Leaflet tracker](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2754) - I think it should be closed here.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem adding a white layer with 1% transparency over my images with transparency before using them on MapTiler.

Using this technique MapTiler created all titles resolving the problem as it doesn't really have a way to figure out what tiles exist before calling them.